# Reading a large text file in C programming using Clion

Tags: c, clion

I have a problem knowing how to read a large text file in CLion c programming application. I don't know where to include the textfile, what commands to use, if I should use shell or just run the code in Clion etc! I am hoping if any of you are experienced with CLion if you could write a step by step from the beginning. I am supposed to read a text file for an assignment and have not been able to start the assignment cause I don't know how to make my C application read the text file!

Would be incredibly grateful if anyone could take their time and help me!

All the best,
A beginner in programming

Comment: Shouldn't this be explained in your course? However [here](https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-read-file) is a link to a small example (which you could have found by searching for _"c reading file"_ in your favorite search engine)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Actually even though Clion is the recommended app to use in my course, the teacher does not know how to do this using CLion. I got confused searching google since there seems to be different ways. I will try the code in the link you sent! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 - write your code**

[image]

**Step 2 - pass location file as argument by configuring execution settings**

[image]

**Step 3 - set location of the file as program argument**

[image]

**Step 4 - have fun with C programming ;)**

Comment: Thank you so much for your guide! :) I will try this!

Comment: Hi again! I think this worked! :)  Now I am trying to write a simple program that reads my text file in C and replaces all alphabetic characters with a question mark. I wrote a line in the text and set the location of the file. I am planning on using isalpha() command to replace the line of characters in the text file with question mark. Not sure how to traverse the textfile. Do you know how to make a c program traverse a textfile? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: What I know is that I want a for loop that changes the aplhabetic characters to "?" symbol, my question is more how to create a for loop in regards to textfile?

Comment: Sorry man ;) That's a whole different story. I suggest starting here (you will find all you need there): https://archive.org/details/the_c_programming_language_2_20181213/mode/2up